# Can't see material on my object

Tags: modeling, materials, node-editor, edit-mode

[image]

As you can see I have applied these nodes to my object but the object has the same material as in the begining,but in a preview menu I can see the material applied,please someone help me,your suggestion and answer is highly appreciated.Thank you!!

Comment: Does it show correctly in Render View? You are in Texture view and the has some limitations.

Comment: Probably you added material in stack but didn't assign it to any faces (note that there are 2 materials on your object). Also node connected to Material Output might not be the final in the tree, thus Material shading will show you approximation for that one

Comment: Hi, can you provide the .blend file to take a look?

Comment: I think, mr Zak is right. Check this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh/517#517